# Find control's properties using appium

Tags: c#, wpf, selenium, automation, appium

I'm using appium in visual studio for testing a simple WPF application,

I'm using WindowsDriver

```
WindowsDriver<WindowsElement> driver = new WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723"), desiredCapabilities);
```

I know how to enter text and how to get text from TextBox:

```
driver.FindElementByAccessibilityId("MyTextBox").SendKeys("123");
```

I wanted to know if there any way to get and set control's properties,
For example: get IsChecked from CheckBox, get Background from TextBlock etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

CheckBox isChecked:

```
bool isChecked = driver.FindElementByAccessibilityId("MyCheckBox").GetAttribute("Toggle.ToggleState") == "1";
```